# aggregate in Mongodb driver(npm) result is different from robo3T result

Tags: node.js, mongodb

its my aggregate in robo3t and node app

```
db.getCollection('roles').aggregate([
{$match:{"_id" : ObjectId("63c8ad93eb3b2d975834a6d0")}},
   {
     $lookup: {
            from: 'modules',
            localField: 'moduleAccess.moduleId',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'moduleData'
          }
        },
        {
            $unwind:'$moduleData'
        }
]).toArray()
```

my result in robo3t and nodejs is :

robo3t :

```
/* 1 */
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("63c8ad93eb3b2d975834a6d0"),
        "roleName" : "SuperUser",
        "activeStatus" : "Active",
        "moduleAccess" : [ 
            {
                "moduleId" : ObjectId("63ca80563eea1005982f82d4"),
                "view" : 1,
                "create" : 1,
                "update" : 1,
                "delete" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "moduleId" : ObjectId("63ca80a13eea1005982f82f8"),
                "view" : 1,
                "create" : 1,
                "update" : 1,
                "delete" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "moduleId" : ObjectId("63ce1de83eea1005982f8f4f"),
                "view" : 1,
                "create" : 1,
                "update" : 1,
                "delete" : 1
            }
        ],
        "moduleData" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("63ca80563eea1005982f82d4"),
            "displayName" : "Module List",
            "moduleName" : "moduleList",
            "moduleIcon" : "fa fa-circle",
            "moduleLevel" : 1,
            "moduleParent" : ObjectId("63ca80a13eea1005982f82f8"),
            "order" : 0,
            "Active" : "Active"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("63c8ad93eb3b2d975834a6d0"),
        "roleName" : "SuperUser",
        "activeStatus" : "Active",
        "moduleAccess" : [ 
            {
                "moduleId" : ObjectId("63ca80563eea1005982f82d4"),
                "view" : 1,
                "create" : 1,
                "update" : 1,
                "delete" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "moduleId" : ObjectId("63ca80a13eea1005982f82f8"),
                "view" : 1,
                "create" : 1,
                "update" : 1,
                "delete" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "moduleId" : ObjectId("63ce1de83eea1005982f8f4f"),
                "view" : 1,
                "create" : 1,
                "update" : 1,
                "delete" : 1
            }
        ],
        "moduleData" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("63ca80a13eea1005982f82f8"),
            "displayName" : "Master App",
            "moduleName" : "masterApp",
            "moduleIcon" : "fa fa-circle",
            "moduleLevel" : 0,
            "moduleParent" : "",
            "order" : 0,
            "Active" : "Active"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("63c8ad93eb3b2d975834a6d0"),
        "roleName" : "SuperUser",
        "activeStatus" : "Active",
        "moduleAccess" : [ 
            {
                "moduleId" : ObjectId("63ca80563eea1005982f82d4"),
                "view" : 1,
                "create" : 1,
                "update" : 1,
                "delete" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "moduleId" : ObjectId("63ca80a13eea1005982f82f8"),
                "view" : 1,
                "create" : 1,
                "update" : 1,
                "delete" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "moduleId" : ObjectId("63ce1de83eea1005982f8f4f"),
                "view" : 1,
                "create" : 1,
                "update" : 1,
                "delete" : 1
            }
        ],
        "moduleData" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("63ce1de83eea1005982f8f4f"),
            "displayName" : "Role",
            "moduleName" : "role",
            "moduleIcon" : "fa fa-circle",
            "moduleLevel" : 1,
            "moduleParent" : ObjectId("63ca80a13eea1005982f82f8"),
            "order" : 1,
            "Active" : "Active"
        }
    }
]
```

in robo3t result is answer as expected. its correct answer

nodejs result :

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("63c8ad93eb3b2d975834a6d0"),
  roleName: 'SuperUser',
  activeStatus: 'Active',
  moduleAccess: [
    {
      moduleId: new ObjectId("63ca80563eea1005982f82d4"),
      view: 1,
      create: 1,
      update: 1,
      delete: 1
    },
    {
      moduleId: new ObjectId("63ca80a13eea1005982f82f8"),
      view: 1,
      create: 1,
      update: 1,
      delete: 1
    },
    {
      moduleId: new ObjectId("63ce1de83eea1005982f8f4f"),
      view: 1,
      create: 1,
      update: 1,
      delete: 1
    }
  ],
  moduleData: {
    _id: new ObjectId("63ca80563eea1005982f82d4"),
    displayName: 'Module List',
    moduleName: 'moduleList',
    moduleIcon: 'fa fa-circle',
    moduleLevel: 1,
    moduleParent: new ObjectId("63ca80a13eea1005982f82f8"),
    order: 0,
    Active: 'Active'
  }
}
```

in nodejs only unwidn 1 data

what i do wrong with my config?

mongodb(npm) : 4.13.0

mongodb version : 5.0.7

node version : 16.14.2

please help to configuration my app the output from node js can be the same as robo3t

Comment: Are you sure, you connected to the same Mongo database?

Comment: yes. im connected to same database